# Why can't I access the memory of the loaded .dll after loading it by loadLibrary() under Windows CE

Tags: windows, windows-mobile, windows-ce

I load a .dll file(PE) by loadLibrary(), and then I want to read the IMAGE_OS_HEADER of this PE. So I use IsBadReadPtr() to check the read access of the memory of the loaded .dll. But IsBadReadPtr() returns false. This code works well on desktop but not well under Windows CE.

Answer (score 0):

- [You shouldn't use `IsBadReadPtr` for anything.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/27/773741.aspx)
- [But if you do, read this first.](http://www.softwareverify.com/software-verify-blog/?p=319)